# cs50x Mario Pyramid does not draw

Tags: c, cs50

I have started the CS50x problem set 1; however my programme seems to stop after I have input the the number for height.

I.e. the programme will ask for a number between 8 and 23 (repetitively until it gets a correct input) and once I do so the code stops.

What have I done wrong here?

Below is the code I have written. All help would be greatly appreciated as I have looked at various questions on here S.E. but none addressing this problem.

---

```
include stdio.h
include cs50.h

int main (void)

{

printf("ok lets make a pyramid :)\n");

    // height = x

    int x;

    // spaces = z

    int z;

    // hashes = a

    int a;

    // Get correct number for height

    do
    {
        printf("Give me a positive number between 8 and 23 for the height of the pyramid\n");
        x = GetInt();
    }

    while (x < 8 || x > 23);

    // Build the phantom pyramid 

    for (int q = 0; q == x; q++)
    {

    // Spaces

        for (z = x - 1; z == 0 ; z--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

            // Hashtags

            for (a = 1; a == q; a++)
            {
                printf("#\n");
            }
    }}
```

---

Comment: maybe you should ask this here: http://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from that your `#include` syntax is wrong (`#include <stdio.h>`), your fundamental problem here, and the reason that your program exits without printing anything, is that the main `for` loop is never entered. C `for` loops are executed while the controlling expression is true, not until is is true. You have:

```
for (int q = 0; q == x; q++){ ... }
```

Since `q == x` evaluates to `0` (false), because `q` is `0` and `x` is between 8 and 23, this loop never executes, and the program exits. Each of your loops has this problem. You can fix it:

```
for (int q = 0; q < x; q++)
    {
    // Spaces

        for (z = x - 1; z > 0 ; z--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

            // Hashtags

            for (a = 0; a <= q; a++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
```

Here, note that in the first pass through the loop, `q` is 0, so `a` must start at 0 to print a single hash on the first line. Also, the newline character is not printed until the loop is finished printing the line. These changes give this output for a height of 8:

```
       #
       ##
       ###
       ####
       #####
       ######
       #######
       ########
```

I am not sure if this is the output that you want. The spacing on the left is tied to the height of the pyramid. If you want the pyramid steps on the left, you can change the associated `for` statement:

```
for (z = x - 1; z > q ; z--)
```

But I was under the impression that the Mario Pyramid had the steps on the left, and two hashes in the top line. You could modify your loop to do this, but here is a different loop. You don't need the variable `a`, and rather than thinking of `z` as "spaces", think of it as representing the line-position:

```
for (int q = x; q > 0; q--) {

    // print spaces at beginning of line
    for (z = 1; z < q; z++) {
        printf(" ");
    }

    // print hashes at end of line
    for ( ; z < x + 2; z++) {
        printf("#");
    }
    // print newline when finished printing line
    printf("\n");
}
```

The new loop gives this output for a height of 8:

```
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
  #######
 ########
#########
```

Comment: hey David i never thanked you for this answer sorry about that.

Comment: sure thing :) me and my wife had a baby since i was last looking at this stuff so I'm having to pick it all up again :/. maybe if i run into some problems in future i can ask for your help?